# Does there exist some method which allows me to ask Bitcoin full nodes, the IP addresses of their recent peers?

Tags: tcp, blockchain, p2p, bitcoin

I read that the Bitcoin network topology is secret, but can I ask to peers which connection they had in past?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getaddr` command, see [Bitcoin Wiki - getaddr](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getaddr).

> The getaddr message sends a request to a node asking for information
>   about known active peers to help with finding potential nodes in the
>   network. The response to receiving this message is to transmit one or
>   more addr messages with one or more peers from a database of known
>   active peers. The typical presumption is that a node is likely to be
>   active if it has been sending a message within the last three hours.

Note that nodes that use an older protocol version than the one you use will be skipped.

Websites such as [bitnodes.io](https://bitnodes.earn.com/dashboard/?days=365) uses `getaddr` provide a count of listening nodes.

> The crawler implementation in Python is available from GitHub
>   (ayeowch/bitnodes) and the crawler deployment is documented in
>   Provisioning [Bitcoin Network Crawler](https://github.com/ayeowch/bitnodes).